# Dynamically create the full URL to my application

Tags: php

I am able to get my application root using

```
 define("ROOT",dirname(__FILE__);
```

but I need to dynamically get the full URL to where my application resides.

Example location on my drive could be at:

```
 c:\htdocs\website_name\index.php
```

then I need:

```
 http://localhost/website_name/
```

Preferabbly with the correct protocol (http or https)

I am currently hard coding the location of the application in my config file but have seen that it can be done dynamically.

Any ideas?
I assume using something like $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] can give me name but I am not sure how to get he remainder of the variable working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I follow you, you mean configure your apache server to point the document root to "C:\htdocs"?

Comment: @Deleteman No. The question is how can code in `c:\htdocs\website_name\index.php` figure out that it's served as `http://localhost/website_name/`. BTW, good question, I'll be working on this problem soon myself. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SERVER_NAME is not automatically told to reflect the actual domain name and path. This is defined in the VirtualHost configuration file usually in apache/conf/extra. You'll need to parse the HTTP_HOST in combination with the SERVER_PROTOCOL and SERVER_PORT to get the real domain name.

```
$domain =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$protocol = (strpos('https', strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])))
          ? 'https'
          : 'http';
$port = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80 || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443 && $protocol != "https")
      ? ":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']
      : "";

$path = sub_str(str_pos("index.php", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), -1,  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$done = $protocol . "://".$domain.$protocol.$path;
```

Code not tested but should show you the flow.

Edit: As for your path name you should parse the PHP_SELF variable, and remove everything starting from index.php (or your script file name).

Comment: And what about `/website_name/`?

Comment: See my edit. It was quick so the string cut might not be correct for $path. So you might need to tweak it.